# How to remove certain files from a bunch of directories?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have around 10 directories from which I want to remove certain files and subdirectories on regular basis. Those files and subdirectories named the same in each directory. I'd look like this in a pseudo language:

```
["dir1", "dir2", "dir3", "dir4"].each do |dir| 
  remove "#{dir}/file1"
  remove "#{dir}/file2"
  remove_rf "#{dir}/sub_dir1"
  remove_rf "#{dir}/sub_dir2"
end
```

How would I do this in bash?

Comment: Please include exact patterns that you require, so we can tell if wildcards are enough or something more complicated is needed.

Comment: @Panki we don't think that that should be included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell equivalent of your pseudo-code is this:

```sh
for dir in dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4; do
    rm "${dir}/file1" "${dir}/file2"
    rm -rf "${dir}/sub_dir1" "${dir}/sub_dir2"
done
```

This can be written differently, for example

```
rm -rf {dir1,dir2,dir3,dir4}/{file1,file2,sub_dir1,sub_dir2}
```

(The behaviour here wouldn’t be *quite* the same: the first implementation would fail with an error if `file1` and `file2` turned out to be directories, whereas the second would delete everything.)